# Revert a jQuery draggable object back to a specific container when is dropped in non-droppable section

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is an example of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/german_martin/hr8Q7/1/

I have a container called "Unassigned container", it has other draggable objects inside ("title A", "title B"...etc.)
And I have other 4 containers called "Container"

Example of my problem: When a user puts "title A" (or other) in "Container" everything works fine, but when a user puts "title ..." outside, this element must go back to "Unassigned container"

Question: Is there a way to make "title ..." to go back to "Unassigned container" when the user puts it outside of "container"?

Image example:

[image: Image example]

```
   $(function () {

        $(".unassignedClassContainer").sortable({
            connectWith: ".container",
            handle: ".title",
            revert: true
        });

        $(".container").sortable({
            connectWith: ".container, .unassignedClassContainer",
            handle: ".title",
            revert: true
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this once. I used the following code for draggables.

```
$(".draggable").draggable( {
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        snap: '#dropSlots',
        snapMode: "inner",
        start: function(){
            Positioning.initialize($(this));
        },
        stop: function() {
            Positioning.reset($(this));
        }
    } );
```

using this:

```
var Positioning = (function () {
    return {
        //Initializes the starting coordinates of the object
        initialize: function (object) {
            if ( object.data("dragged") != "1" ) {
                object.data("dragged", "1");
                object.data("originalLocation", $(this).originalPosition = {top:0,left:0});
            }
        },
        //Resets the object to its starting coordinates
        reset: function (object) {
            if ( object.data("dragged") == "1" && object.data("inDroppable") != "1" ){
                var OriginalLocationTop = object.data("originalLocation").top;
                var OriginalLocationLeft = object.data("originalLocation").left;
                $(object).animate({top: OriginalLocationTop, left: OriginalLocationLeft}, 1500);
            }
        },
    };
})();
```

As you can see it uses `object.data("inDroppable")` this was set when a draggable was dropped on a droppable.

Droppable code:

```
$('.droppable').droppable( {
     drop: handleQuestionDrop,
     out: handleQuestionMoveOut,
     tolerance: "pointer"
} );
```

This is using the following 2 functions:

```
function handleQuestionMoveOut( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.draggable).data("inDroppable", "0");
    // A lot of other project related stuff, deleted...
}

function handleQuestionDrop( event, ui ) {

    // position draggable directly on top of the slot
    ui.draggable.position( {                
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left top',
        of: $(this),
        using: function(css, calc) {
            ui.draggable.animate(css, 250, "linear");
        }           
    } );

    $(ui.draggable).data("inDroppable", "1");
}
```

As you can see it's a lot of code, and I removed all irrelevant code already.
So what does this code implement is the following:

1. Give your draggables a "starting coordinate" on dragging for the first time.
2. On stopping of dragging these draggables check if they landed in a drop spot.

   - If they did, position it on top of the slot.
   - If they did not, position them on top of their original coordinates

Feel free to ask any question ;)